# One-to-one relations with sfGuardPlugin

Tags: symfony-1.4

I've added the following class in my schema.yml (I'm using symfony 1.4):

```
LoginKey:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sos_login_key
  options:
    type: InnoDB
    collate: utf8_unicode_ci
    charset: utf8
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
      notnull: true
    user_id:
      notnull: true
      type: integer(8)
    keycode:
      notnull: true
      type: string(255)
    expires_at:
      type: datetime
      default: null
  relations:
    sfGuardUser:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      type: one

sfGuardUser:
  relations:
    LoginKey:
      local: id
      foreign: user_id
      type: one
```

Now when I try to do a JOIN on those tables in a query (sfGuardUser innerJoin LoginKey), the LoginKey records don't get hydrated; I see a new query is done for every row as I'm trying to access the LoginKey.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owning side of the relation is the `LoginKey` so you have to define the relation only there. Add `foreignType: one` and remove the `sfGuardUser` part. So a correct schema looks something like this:

```
LoginKey:
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer
      notnull: true
    keycode:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    expires_at:
      type: datetime
      default: null
  relations:
    sfGuardUser:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      foreignType: one
```

And as a side note if you want to extend the schema of a plugin you have to use the `package` parameter (but in your case it is not required as no new fields have to be added to `sfGuardUser`)

```
sfGuardUser:
  package:
    sfDoctrineGuardPlugin.lib.model.doctrine
  relations:...
```

When not using this the classes will be generated into a wrong location and will conflict with others so you have to remove those classes. Try `php symfony doctrine:clean` and check if it's removed all unused classes (`sfGuardUser`) from `lib/model` and `lib/model/base`.

Comment: Great, thanks, that definitely looks better. Despite the changes I'm still experiencing the hydrating problem though. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Did you removed duplicate `sfGuardUser` classes (from `lib/model/base` too)? Regenerated the model and cleared the cache? What you have tried? `$user->getLoginKey();`?

Comment: I just realized I had left an overloaded version of getLoginKey(), which was the culprit... feeling dumb right now ;) Thanks for your help!